# 2wire router - every 600 seconds latency jumps up for 110 seconds

Tags: hardware, router, wifi

Exactly every 600 seconds (10 minutes) my 2wire 2701HG-B has latency go from around 15ms to between 400ms and 800ms. This lasts for between 108 seconds and 113 seconds averaging 110 seconds.

This is true for both wired and wireless. I've tried it on multiple computers and it is still the same issue.

I disabled all wireless encryption and it didn't help. I restored factory settings, put back the bare minimum, and it doesn't help.

Does anyone have any ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel very embarrassed posting this, but it might help others.

I had a machine that was plugged into the network, that every 10 minutes would attempt to send a huge email. The upload time was about 110 seconds and after that the email server would reject it, and the client would re-queue it for sending. So, killing that email in the queue, fixed all my problems.

In short, a client was saturating my upsteam which destroyed my latency (had to wait for packets).

Comment: +1 for posting the solution, even though it may be embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying the latest firmware updates?

Comment: yes. there are no updates for about the last 6 months.